# compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, devtools

Even though I followed the instructions to configure as shown in the image below, I still cannot find the compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running

Does anyone have this error or know how to fix it?

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I followed the instructions but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

The option has been moved to "Advanced Settings" as "Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running"